# Tracking element visibility due to z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I rummaged all internet to find answer for question: 
'**How to really recognize HTML element visible on page**'.
There are few ways to hide element and we can track its visibility:

- Using css style 'display:none'.
- Using css style 'visibility:hidden'.
- Using css style 'opacity:0'.
- Using css style 'position:absolute' and adding style 'top:-%SOME_PIXELS%px' or 'left:-%SOME_PIXELS%px.

But I collided with some interesting case: **element we're looking for visibility placed under other element that is positioned absolutely**

Example:

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="1">
 <span>
   <div style='width:300px;height:250px;background-color:red ;'></div>
 </span>
</div>

 <div style="position:absolute;top:8px;left:8px;" id="2">
   <span>
     <div style='width:300px;height:250px;background-color:green ;'></div>
   </span>
 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

E.g. in this case we're looking for element with **id=1** appears to be hidden.

How I can track visibility without z-index in this case ?

Comment: I've updated the question to refer to z-index because previously you were using the word "overridden", which has a specific meaning in CSS. I think this better encapsulates your question. Feel free to rollback if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set z-index, the element with **id=2** will on the top of **id=1**, because the green rectangle (id=2) is defined after the red one (id=1).

If you want to hide the green one, simple add "z-index: -1;" in the div style. Since the default z-index is 0.

References: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp